# python code to compare the pairs of sentences, and see if they are in the same or different blocks in text file

Tags: python, nlp

I've 2 text files. Writing a Python Program for the following
1)I need to compare the pairs of sentences in the 1st file, and see if they are in the same or different blocks, and compare that to the 2nd text file.
2)I need to calculate the percentage of correct classification.
3) I need to  count:
% of sentence pairs correctly classified as in the same block, % of sentence pairs correctly classified as in different blocks

Answer (score 0):

Please provide more information about the structure of the files. Also, I'd like to remind you that StackOverFlow helps you out providing aditional information in order to solve your problem, we are not going to code the solution for you.

Provide aditional information and your code if possible in order to help you out.

Have a great day.

Comment: Thank you Mr Sebastain for the reply. Yes,Im aware that StackoverFlow will provide me only the path to solve my problem Not the Code. The files are text files (.txt extension). They are the text versions youtube videos of the class presented by Professor.